How to store an authorization token to connect with external API?
I am working on a site that needs to validate a set of phone numbers using an external API that verifies the call in two steps- oAuth validation and verification of phone number status. This API is provided by a Telco company that has their own user base, categorized as "Silver", "Gold" and "Platinum". The TelCo has provided a documentation that contains all the necessary credentials (client_id, client_secret etc) .
What I am finding difficult to implement due to my limited understanding with API is the followings, and would appreciate it if I could get pointed to the right direction-

Every time my oAuth validation makes an outbound request, it generates an access token of type Bearer Token which is dynamic on each call. Do I have to store that token for each call? If yes, how do I do that without the use of any plugin? (I am using the free version of WP Get API to make the oAuth verification and it is successfully making the call, but it does not allow to store the access token and i want to store it manually). I also have tested the API in postman and its returning the intended result, but I am unable to figure out how to implement the same in WordPress.

Once the access token is stored and verified, I need to do the validation of user base in either during checkout/using forminator form that will then apply a specific discount on a product. I am trying to validate the phone number during check out but my preference is to use forminator to validate and apply discount based on the phone number.


This is what I am still learning PHP and API and want to understand what I am doing wrong here. This is what I have added in my functions.php-
function verify_api_phonenumber($customer_status) {
if (isset($_POST['billing_phone'])) {
    $coupon_code = false;
    
    if ($phonenumber_in_api) {

        switch ($customer_status) {

            case 'gold':
                $coupon_code = 'gold1';
                break;
        }
    }
}

if ($coupon_code && !WC()->cart->has_discount($coupon_code)) {
    WC()->cart->apply_coupon($coupon_code);
}
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'verify_api_phonenumber');

